# ajax call download fails on chrome works on firefox

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

Hello I am using spout to run some excel reports. I have a user interface where they input date, model, and other information then I do a GET to send it to a php script where I run a query and then put all the results into an excel file like this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
require_once 'spout-2.7.2/src/Spout/Autoloader/autoload.php'; // don't forget to change the path!
use Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory;
use Box\Spout\Writer\WriterFactory;
use Box\Spout\Common\Type;

$reportDate=date("Ymd_hhmmss");
$filename="combined_report".$reportDate.".xlsx";

include ("../log/connectionToDb.php");
$conn = connectionSQL();

//provide error if connection fails
if (!$conn) {
  echo "An error occurred.\n";
  exit;
}

//connected successfully to db. Do not echo anything otherwise it will not show up on dropdown.
else {

//echo "connected";
}

  //From date and to date static in case not provided by user 
$fromDate = $_GET['convertedFrom'];
$toDate = $_GET['convertedTo'];
$line= $_GET['selectedLine'];
$model_num=$_GET['modelNumber'];




$writer = WriterFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
ob_start();
$writer->openToBrowser($filename);
$sheet = $writer->getCurrentSheet();
$sheet->setName('Production Data');
$rowCount = 2; 
$flag=false;


$production = "query";  


//echo memory_get_usage() ;
$result1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $production);

if($result1 === FALSE){
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), TRUE));
}

do{
      if(!$flag) {

          $headerRow = ['line', 'Work order','Model number', 'Revision','Serial number','Lpn','Date created','Date completed'];
           $writer->addRow($headerRow);
          $flag = true; 
      }
      else{

          $reportRow = [$row['line'], $row['work_order'], $row['model_num'], $row['revision'],$row['serial_num'],$row['LPN'],$row['date_created'],$row['date_completed']];
           $writer->addRow($reportRow);

          $rowCount++; 
     }  
}
 while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1));



$writer->close();
$xlsData = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_clean();
$response =  array(


           'op' => 'ok',
            'file' => "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,".base64_encode($xlsData)
        );


   }
die(json_encode($response));
```

Then on the AJAX call I have the following:

```
 $.ajax({
    url:  'modelData/excel-export.php',
    method: "GET",
    data: {'modelNumber':modelNumber,'convertedFrom':converted_from_UTC,'convertedTo':converted_to_UTC,'selectedLine':selectedLine},
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(fileCreated){
    }

}).done(function(data){
   console.log(local);
var $a = $("<a>");
$a.attr("href",data.file);
$("body").append($a);
$a.attr("download","combined_report_"+local+".xlsx");
$a[0].click();
$a.remove();
  });
```

now if I run this in Firefox everything works I am able to download up to 4 months of data which is >60,000 records this has no problem. If I run this in google chrome I cannot download more than 1 week about 20,000 records and U get a "download failed -network error"  I was using PHPExcel but then found out it didn't support too many records so I switched to spout but I find the same issue only in google chrome but I don't understand where this limitation is coming from. I have read multiple posts and I have tried setting headers, lengths etc but nothing has worked also I chatted with a spout forum and they said none of the headers were necessary but they were still unable to help me.

I think this question [Download failed - network error in google chrome but working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345139/download-failed-network-error-in-google-chrome-but-working-in-firefox) may be going close to the same direction as my issue.

Also I have tried running incognito mode chrome I have tried disabling all extensions

As a side note...The firefox download appears to work fine but we don't "support" firefox so it would be hard for customers to go to multiple browsers specially when they're not tech savy

Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Why not just call the server and have it add the proper headers to cause it to be downloaded? Why make the Ajax call?

Comment: @epascarello so if I try that I don't need to add the .done part I should just do the request and the download should work? sorry I am very new with all this and there are a lot of quesitons on how to do this with PHPExcel but not with spout so it makes it hard to find answers

Comment: I tried like this: `var local=(moment(today).format('YYYYMMDD_hhmmss'));
 var url = "modelData/excel-export.php";
 var params = "modelNumber="+modelNumber+"&convertedFrom="+converted_from_UTC+"&convertedTo="+converted_to_UTC+"&selectedLine="+selectedLine;
 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

http.open("GET", url+"?"+params, true);
http.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
        hideLoading();
    }
}
http.send(null);`

Comment: I am jsut getting a response like this : `{"op":"ok","file":"data:application\/vnd.ms-excel;base64,UEsDBBQAAAAIAC1oi0o6hQ\/ETgEAAMkEAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbM2Uy27CMBBF93xF5G0VG1hUVZXAoo9li1T6Aa49IRaObXkMhb\/vJIEKISpRUaRm41h3Zu7xY1xMN43N1hDA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by doing the following:

JS

```
window.open("modelData/excel-export.php?modelNumber="+modelNumber+"&convertedFrom="+converted_from_UTC+"&convertedTo="+converted_to_UTC+"&selectedLine="+selectedLine,
  '_blank'// <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
  );
```

then on the PHP side:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
require_once 'spout-2.7.2/src/Spout/Autoloader/autoload.php'; // don't forget to change the path!
use Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory;
use Box\Spout\Writer\WriterFactory;
use Box\Spout\Common\Type;

$reportDate=date("Ymd_hhmmss");
$filename="combined_report".$reportDate.".xlsx";

include ("../log/connectionToDb.php");
$conn = connectionSQL();

//provide error if connection fails
if (!$conn) {
  echo "An error occurred.\n";
  exit;
}

//connected successfully to db. Do not echo anything otherwise it will not show up on dropdown.
else {

//echo "connected";
}

  //From date and to date static in case not provided by user 
$fromDate = $_GET['convertedFrom'];
$toDate = $_GET['convertedTo'];
$line= $_GET['selectedLine'];
$model_num=$_GET['modelNumber'];




$writer = WriterFactory::create(Type::XLSX);
$writer->openToBrowser($filename);
$sheet = $writer->getCurrentSheet();
$sheet->setName('Production Data');
$rowCount = 2; 
$flag=false;


$production = "query";  


//echo memory_get_usage() ;
$result1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $production);

if($result1 === FALSE){
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), TRUE));
}

do{
      if(!$flag) {

          $headerRow = ['line', 'Work order','Model number', 'Revision','Serial number','Lpn','Date created','Date completed'];
           $writer->addRow($headerRow);
          $flag = true; 
      }
      else{

          $reportRow = [$row['line'], $row['work_order'], $row['model_num'], $row['revision'],$row['serial_num'],$row['LPN'],$row['date_created'],$row['date_completed']];
           $writer->addRow($reportRow);

          $rowCount++; 
     }  
}
 while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1));



$writer->close();
```

The library I am using just doesn't work very well with AJAX so this approach solved my issue. Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I used Blob Javascript for the same problem.
this link maybe help someone : 
[Blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/b64-to-blob)